# How to keep track of Chrome tab's PID in Python?

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome

I'm working on a program that requires me to keep track of the PIDs of specific Chrome/browser instances. This is the code I wrote for this:

```
def launch_procs():
    low1 = Popen(['google-chrome-stable', 'http://www.google.com'])
    med1 = Popen(['google-chrome-stable', 'http://www.netflix.com'])
    high1 = Popen(['google-chrome-stable', 'http://www.facebook.com'])
    return [low1.pid, med1.pid, high1.pid]
```

However, when I attempt to reference the PIDs later on in the program it seems that the PIDs have expired. Here is the error I get:

```
7894
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such process
7896
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such process
7901
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such process
```

Is the issue that Chrome doesn't assign permanent PIDs to its tabs/processes (i.e. it forks once a Chrome process launches and ditches the parent process)?

Note: This implementation is browser/implementation agnostic, I just need a way to obtain stable access to the PIDs of these launched processes. If anyone has suggestions on doing this they would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it possible to show the code you are referring to "later on in the program"?

Comment: As this is research code I'm not allowed to share that much, but I can post the most relevant part: `    for pid in vm_list:`
`        print(pid)`
`        os.system('sudo timeout 10 strace -p ' + str(pid) + ' -o temp.out | cat temp.out | tail -' + str(line_count) + ' > ' + outfile)` The vm_list is supposed to be the PIDs gathered from Chrome. For each loop I'm printing the results of the strace to an output file and doing some stuff with it.

Comment: I can't get the formatting right for whatever reason, my apologies.

Comment: I updated my response, `chrome` does not allow `root` to run sessions for security reasons.  There are work arounds though, let me know if the edits in the snippet help.

Comment: @bearface Did you ever figure a way out to keep track of the individual tabs' PIDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not run as root under normal operating conditions.  You can find several discussions for this [here](https://ubuntuforums.orgshowthread.php?t=1743565) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175967/how-to-run-google-chrome-as-root-in-linux)

There are several arguments that will allow you to circumvent this.  By passing `--user-data-dir` and `--no-sandbox` you will be able to run chrome as `root`.

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen


line_count = 10
outfile = 'foo.txt'
cmd = 'sudo timeout 10 strace -p {} -o temp.out | cat temp.out | tail -{} > {}'
tab_sites = ['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.msn.com']


for site in tab_sites:
    chrome_proc = Popen(['google-chrome-stable', site, '--user-data-dir', '--no-sandbox']) 
    print(chrome_proc.pid)
    os.system(cmd.format(chrome_proc.pid, line_count, outfile))
```

Alternatively you can use [`runuser`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/runuser) with your command:

```
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen


line_count = 10
outfile = 'foo.txt'
cmd = 'sudo timeout 10 strace -p {} -o temp.out | cat temp.out | tail -{} > {}'
tab_sites = ['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.msn.com']


for site in tab_sites:
    chrome_proc = Popen(['runuser', '-u', sys.argv[1], 'google-chrome-stable', site]) 
    print(chrome_proc.pid)
    os.system(cmd.format(chrome_proc.pid, line_count, outfile))
```

Just pass in the username you want to run this under, `sudo python trace_chrome.py your_user_name`

I understand you aren't able to show your exact code which does make things tougher to be able to assist.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I think the issue I'm having is that the PIDs returned by Popen are different from what the PIDs end up being. So when I try and do what you did programmatically, strace is unable to attach to the processes. Are you manually grabbing the PIDs from the Chrome GUI or is Popen working correctly for you?

Answer (score 0):

To see the Process ID's of your Chrome tabs you can open the Task Manager by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>. I did some testing, and as you suspect, the PID is different than reported by `Popen`.

One way to get an accessable PID with Chrome is to use the option  `--temp-profile` to create a new session for each  site instead of using an existing one.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using `--temp-profile` and it still had the same problem. I've tried looking into other solutions such as using Firefox, but from what I've read Firefox runs all tabs under a single process. I need to run these tabs concurrently and run diagnostics individually so I'm not sure if I can actually do that at this point.